# New java font's size is always 1

Tags: java, fonts, font-size, truetype

I added a new font for my project in java. However upon rendering it the text size is always at 1 it appears. The text basically appears as just a few little lines. I tried this with multiple fonts and they all did it. This is my code.

```
public static void intializeFonts(){       
    try{
        File font = new File("C:/The Woods/Fonts/script.ttf");
        Font scriptFontU = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, font);
        Font scriptFont = scriptFontU.deriveFont(20);
        script = new TrueTypeFont(scriptFont, false);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error Loading Font");
    }            
}
```

This is also what I am using to render it if this helps.

```
    g.setFont(Fonts.script);
    g.drawString("Weight: "+ItemContainer.getWeight()+"lbs", 30, 600);
```

Any help would be great. Thank You.

Comment: Solved, I used a outprint to find the name the font was using in the system, and then did new font() rather then deriveFont() and it worked.

Comment: As I mention in my answer, the reason `deriveFont` didn't work was because you called the wrong overload. Your workaround is correct (and a better solution) if you're always dealing with registered system fonts, but if your font is included as a resource you'll want to use your original approach.

Comment: Note that it's okay to "Answer" and "Accept" your own question.  It's a good way to document the solution.

Comment: Ya I realized shortly after posting that the only reason it was working was because I had it in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `scriptFontU.deriveFont(20)`, you are calling `Font.deriveFont(int)`. In this function, the first argument is an integer representing a style. Instead, you want to call `Font.deriveFont(float)`, which takes a size and leaves the style unchanged. You can do this by calling `scriptFontU.deriveFont(20.0)`, or equivalent; or call `Font.deriveFont(int, float)` as `scriptFontU.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20.0)` to make it unambiguous.